# Reading time as character array in c

Tags: c, arrays

I am a newbie to C character arrays. And I know that to read character arrays we need to use %s format specifier using scanf or gets.

I am reading time as two character array's in C as h[2] and m[2] where h represents hours and m represents minutes.

```
char h[2],m[2];
scanf("%s:%s",h,m);

printf("%s:%s",h,m);
```

But when I give `11:30` as input it prints time as `11:30::30` as output. Can anyone say me the reason?

Thank you.

Comment: Save yourself future grief - never use `gets()`.  Note that it is no longer part of the C standard library.

Comment: Read about [strptime(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strptime.3.html) & [strftime(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strftime.3.html). Your system might have them.

Answer (score 2):

You are forgetting to do a few things:

- Your character arrays need to be null terminated. Create `h` and `m` with a size of 3 instead of 2, allowing for a null character, `'\0'`, to be placed after the string. `scanf` does this for you.
- You can limit the size of the input string with `scanf`. `scanf("%2s", h)` would place a string of 2 characters from `stdin` into `h`.
- You could also exclude the `:` character from the first string: `scanf("%[^:]:%s", h, m)`

Putting all of this together, we get:

```
char h[3], m[3]; // Create two character arrays of 3 characters.
if (scanf("%2[^:]:%2s", h, m) == 2) { // Read the time given and check that two items were read (as suggested by chux)
    printf("%s:%s", h, m); // Print the time given.
}
```

Comment: What if I don't mention '2' width in format specifier? Doesn't it stop reading after reading 2 characters?

Comment: That is what I believed would happen, however when I had tested it, the colon character was being included in h, making it extend over into m's memory when printing.

Comment: See my most recent edit for another solution which excludes the colon from the first string.

Comment: Using `scanf("%[^:]:%s", h, m);` does not limit user input, possible causing overruns in `h` and `m`.  `printf("%s:%s", h, m); ` with first checking `scanf()` results can lead to printing uninitialized arrays.  Suggest `if (scanf(" %2[^:]:%2s", h, m) == 2) printf("%s:%s", h, m);`

Answer (score 0):

try this two options, i hope they will satisfy you:

1-

```
char h[3], m[3];

printf("Input time\n");


scanf("%s%s", &h, &m);
printf("\n%s:%s\n", h, m);

return 0;
```

2-

```
int i;
char ch, hour[6];

printf("Input time\nex. HH:MM\n");


while(ch!='\n')
{
    ch=getchar();
    hour[i]=ch;
    i++;
}

hour[i]='\0';
printf("\n");
printf("Time: %s\n", hour);
return 0;
```